# Bind DataTemplate with ViewModel and View. WP8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to Bind in my MainPage.xaml Resource a ViewModel with a View together. Like in WPF.
But in WP8, result that DataType is not recognized and I doesn't find much solution searching on google.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel}">
        <v:View></v:View>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Is there a another way to make it? I want to put together a View and ViewModel in my MainPage.

Thanks for all!

Comment: In this case try use `DataTemplateSelector`. [`Example on the CodeProject`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113152/Applying-Data-Templates-Dynamically-by-Type-in-WP7).

Comment: There is no such thing as DataType in WP SDK. As already mentioned try the DataTemplateSelector.